# How can I programmatically add an Artifact to the MavenProject?

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, aether

I am writing a Maven plugin and I would like to automatically resolve specific dependencies and add them as dependencies to the project based on the parameters given to the plugin.

I have been able to successfully resolve dependencies through [aether](http://www.sonatype.com/people/2011/01/how-to-use-aether-in-maven-plugins/), but there seems to be a disconnect between aether and the MavenProject.

There is a method on MavenProject#addAttachedArtifact which I'm guessing is what I want to use. However, it takes a org.apache.maven.artifact.Artifact while the one retrieved from aether is org.sonatype.aether.artifact.Artifact. I found a [plugin](http://projects.reficio.org/p2-maven-plugin/1.0.0/faq.html) that has a conversion method between the two, but I figure there ought to be a more standard approach.

I have also tried using the DefaultArtifactFactory to create a org.apache.maven.artifact.Artifact but get a NullPointerException when trying to get an ArtifactHandler.

**code:**

```
DefaultArtifactFactory factory = new DefaultArtifactFactory();
Artifact mavenArtifact = factory.createBuildArtifact("com.beust", "jcommander", "1.27", "jar");
```

**result:**

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
         at org.apache.maven.artifact.factory.DefaultArtifactFactory.createArtifact(DefaultArtifactFactory.java:155)
         at org.apache.maven.artifact.factory.DefaultArtifactFactory.createArtifact(DefaultArtifactFactory.java:117)
         at org.apache.maven.artifact.factory.DefaultArtifactFactory.createArtifact(DefaultArtifactFactory.java:111)
         at org.apache.maven.artifact.factory.DefaultArtifactFactory.createBuildArtifact(DefaultArtifactFactory.java:75)
         at com.foo.bar.module.IncludeModuleFrontEndMojo.execute(IncludeModuleFrontEndMojo.java:165)
         at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
         ... 20 more
```

So really, these are the things I've tried, a resolution to these issues would be great, but I'm really after the **right** way to do this. Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

I wrote my own conversion method between the two classes:

```
private static org.apache.maven.artifact.Artifact aetherToMavenArtifactBasic(Artifact artifact, String scope, ArtifactHandler artifactHandler) {
    DefaultArtifact mavenArtifact = new DefaultArtifact(artifact.getGroupId(), artifact.getArtifactId(), artifact.getVersion(), scope, artifact.getExtension(), artifact.getClassifier(), artifactHandler);
    mavenArtifact.setFile(artifact.getFile());
    mavenArtifact.setResolved(true);
    return mavenArtifact;
}
```

and found that the MavenProject#addAttachedArtifact method is to attach an artifact to an existing artifact (i.e. attach sources/javadocs jars to an artifact), which is not my goal. Instead I got the artifacts from the maven project and add my artifact:

```
project.getArtifacts().add(mavenArtifact);
```

which adds my artifact to the project (my artifact is then shown when I call the project's getArtifactMap() and getCompileClasspathElements(). However, this change does not persist. This is the problem I was really worried about. So the question has evolved into:

**Can I make changes to the MavenProject and have it persist?**

Comment: If it already exists and you know about it, will you tell me? :). I updated the title to clarify. I'm looking to programatically add a dependency.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible and for my purposes I decided instead to require the user to add the dependency in the project's pom file (and error out if they don't have it).

It seems to be by design that you don't allow the user to muck with the project configuration through a plugin to a point where you could break the build. I found a [good post on advanced MOJO development here](https://reg.maestrodev.com/better-builds-with-maven/developing-custom-maven-plugins/advanced-mojo-development/). A quote from it:

> If this parameter could be specified separately from the main
>   dependencies section, users could easily break their builds –
>   particularly if the mojo in question compiled project source code. In
>   this case, direct configuration could result in a dependency being
>   present for compilation, but being unavailable for testing. Therefore,
>   the @readonly annotation functions to force users to configure the
>   POM, rather than configuring a specific plugin only.